# Is it possible to stream from my Mac to my Wii?

Tags: macos, mac, streaming, wii

I've got a lot of ripped movies and TV shows backed-up on an external drive connected to an iMac. The original media is now in storage (loft) to keep them safe.

I'd like to stream my this media from my iMac (bedroom/"office") to my Wii (livingroom) so I'm not being anti-social with family. Both are connected to the same home network via a Linksys WRT54G router running DD-WRT.

Is this possible?

What software will I need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**[Wii Media Center X](http://www.redkawa.com/mediacenters/wiimediacenterx/)** allows you to stream certain types of pictures, music, videos and files from your computer (where the server is running) to your Nintendo Wii.

mind you, the video capabilities of the Wii are rather limited, flash is as good as it gets.

Comment: Can't seem to find an actual download for Wii Media Center X. Their site bounces to another website without the file. Will keep hunting.

Comment: found this MU link: http://www.megaupload.com/?d=BF0PPI1P

Comment: and this brief tutorial: http://forums.qj.net/wii-accessories-mods-media/90869-wii-media-center-x-installation-mac-os-x.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Internet Channel you can use [WiiTransfer](http://www.riverfold.com/software/wiitransfer/). It does more than just videos as well.

The marketing schtick from their website:

> Wii Transfer can share your movies, music, and pictures directly to your Nintendo Wii using the Internet Channel. Copy Miis from your Wii back to your Mac and save them as images. Browse iTunes playlists and iPhoto albums on your television. Convert your movies to formats the Wii understands, either streaming directly from your Mac or for playback in the Wii's Photo Channel. Wii Transfer can even manage saved game backups copied to an SD card.

Comment: And that Internet Channel is free nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

There is a port of [MPlayer v0.7 for the Wii](http://ronwarez.com/mplayerwii/) which will allow you to mount SMB shares and play just about every video file.  (However I haven't had success with MKV files in 720p.)  This does require the Homebrew Channel.

Answer (score 0):

try this...it requires homebrew, but it's the easiest solution I've been able to find:

http://cosmoknot.blogspot.com/2009/11/stream-movies-from-your-mac-to-your-wii.html